# Set difference between unions of specific subfields

Tags: python, mongodb, set, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a large collection that can be modeled more or less as the one created by the following code:

```
import string
from random import randint, random, choice


documents = []


for i in range(100):
    letters =  choice(string.letters[0:15])

    documents.append({'hgvs_id': "".join([str(randint(0,9)), letters]),
                      'sample_id': "CDE",
                     'number': i*random()*50 - 30 })

    documents.append({'hgvs_id': "".join([str(randint(0,9)), letters]),
              'sample_id': 'ABC',
              'number': i*random()*50 - 30 })

    documents.append({'hgvs_id': "".join([str(randint(0,9)), letters]),
                      'sample_id': 'GEF',
                      'number': i*random()*50 - 30 })


for i in range(10):    # add some unique values for sample_id 'ABC'

    letters = choice(string.letters[0:15])
    documents.append({'hgvs_id': "55" + letters,
                      'sample_id': 'ABC',
                      'number': i*random()*50 - 30 })

collection.insert_many(documents)
```

I am trying to retrieve the **unique** `hgvs_id`'s that occur within documents that have a specific `sample_id` (`ABC` here) but not in documents containing the other two. Usually, there will be many more `sample_id` than just three.

It sounds pretty simple, but so far I have been unsuccessful. Given the size of the collection I'm working with (~30GB), I've been trying to use the `aggregate` framework as follows:

```
sample_1 = collection.aggregate(
    [
            {'$group':
                    {
                    '_id': '$hgvs_id',

                    #'sample_id' : {"addToSet": '$hgvs_id'},
                    'matchedDocuments':
                                    {'$push':
                                            {
                                                    'id': '$_id',
                                                    'sample_name': "$sample_id",
                                                    'hgvs_ids': "$hgvs_id"
                                            }
                                    },
                    }
            },
            {'$match': {
                   "$and": [
                            {'matchedDocuments': {"$elemMatch": {'sample_name': 'ABC'}}},
                            # Some other operation????
                           ]
                     }
   } 
])  #, allowDiskUse=True) may be needed
```

This returns (understandably) all the `hgvs_id`'s having `sample_id` equal `ABC`. Any leads would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Something like `collection.distinct('hgvs_id', {'sample_id': 'ABC'})`

Comment: That would return also the hgvs_ids that may be in the other two samples. I'm trying to find the unique hgvs_ids unique to that sample _and_ that do not occur in documents having other sample names. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: and ....
where exactly you import random?  so that you can use random.random, rrandom.choice ? etc...

Comment: @nickmilon edited. But not really relevant

Comment: @Veeram  is right 'distinct' is the answer
BTW keep it simple,  never mess with aggregation framework if a single operation can solve your problem

Comment: It's not the answer. I specified quite clearly that 'distinct' would give me values I don't need. I.e. hgvs_ids that are in documents from other samples.

Comment: Plus, distinct fails miserably due to the size of the collection

Comment: @Veeram IMO it is relevant, pitty he has done a good job specifying his problem except some minor things. But then again it would be much more easier for me to help by pasting his code and replicate the issue, but then I have to start fixing this  and that, so I give up.

Comment: I agree `distinct` bear some relevance and I was well aware of it. However I would not have resorted to the aggregation framework if that was the solution. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @nickmilon Reading the conversation, what you and @Veeram missed here is that given three documents `{ "k": 1, "v": "A" }, { "k": 1, "v": "B" }, { "k": 2, "v": "A" }` then what the op is expecting is the "third" document only. What `.distinct("k", { "v": "A"})` would return is both 1 and 2 for k, when it's only meant to be 2. That's the simplified form of what the question actually asks. So you need the grouping first before you can filter. The opposite of `.distinct()` in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the **only** `sample_id` in the "set" of grouped values then the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) will be **one**:

With MongoDB 3.4 you can use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) in combination:

```
[
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$hgvs_id",
    "samples": { "$addToSet": "$sample_id" }
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { 
        "$and": [
          { "$in": [ "ABC", "$samples" ] },
          { "$eq": [ { "$size": "$samples" }, 1 ] }
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
]
```

Otherwise use [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) which is just a little longer in syntax:

```
[
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$hgvs_id",
    "samples": { "$addToSet": "$sample_id" }
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { 
        "$and": [
          { "$eq": [ { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$samples", ["ABC"] ] } }, 1 ] },
          { "$eq": [ { "$size": "$samples" }, 1 ] }
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
]
```

Or probably in the simplest form for all versions supporting aggregation anyway:

```
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$hgvs_id",
    "samples": { "$addToSet": "$sample_id" }
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "$and": [{ "samples": "ABC" },{ "samples": { "$size": 1 } }]
  }}
]
```

The same principle applies to any number of arguments in that the "set" produced much much the size of the arguments given as well as containing the specific value.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Great observation on the fact that `$size` would be one. Thank you.

Comment: @CarloMazzaferro Mileage may vary on whether it's "best" to create the "set" of sample_id or rather the hgvs_id depending on the size of the "sets" produced for actual performance, but the principle remains the same. I would indeed recommend turning on `allowDiskUse` in any rate.

Comment: First option works fine and is pretty readable. Usually the size of sample_id <<< hgvs_id , so as is it should be optimal.